# AirPrint driver not visible for Printer Canon TR4550 connected over WiFi. MacOs 10.15

Tags: wifi, printing, driver, bonjour, airprint

I have a printer Canon TR4550 connected over WiFi.
MacOs 10.15.

When I go to Add Printer dialog, it is listed, with Kind = Bonjour.

But in `Use:`, there is supposed to be `AirPrint` driver, which it is not.

What should I do? Canon offers no printers, referring to AirPrint.

[image]

Comment: Which drivers are available in the "Use:" list? It may be possible to use it with a "general" driver.

Comment: For the record, according to https://support.apple.com/HT201311, the Canon TR4550 supports AirPrint.